# Kill modem-manager process

Tags: 3g, modem-manager

I would like to use the script `sakis3g`. And I need to kill modem-manager in order to use it.
I use `sudo killall modem-manager` but process keeps restarting. Is there a way to kill it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have two thing

1. remove the modem manger
2. or remove the D-BUS file from `/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.ModemManager.service` 
   this file wich run the modem manger every two min 
   you can copy it to another place if you don't want to lose it